# In frictionless banking, how can the normal force $N$ be greater than the weight force $mg$ if the car is not accelerating upwards?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force

Based on my understanding in frictionless banking, the vertical component of the normal force must be equal to weight force for the horizontal component be the centripetal force. This means that the normal force has to be greater in magnitude than the weight force. However, a given for centripetal motion is that the car should remain horizontally leveled. Thus, if the car has no upward acceleration, how can the normal force be greater than weight force?

Comment: I think you are correct. Can you show us what you are being shown / taught, so we can make a better judge of what the teacher is trying to say?

Answer (score 2):

> if the car has no upward acceleration, how can the normal force be greater than weight force?

The normal force is not upward. It is perpendicular to the surface.

The direction perpendicular to the surface is diagonal, and can be broken into a horizontal and a vertical component. The vertical component is equal to the weight which eliminates the vertical acceleration, and the horizontal component is the centripetal force.

The total force will therefore have a magnitude greater than the weight because it is not a vertical force, and only the vertical component is limited by the weight.